# Is this ruby-on-rails rspec code good practice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, railstutorial.org

This code is working but I want to check that it's robust/good practice/idiomatic.
Background: I'm following Michael Hartl's rails tutorial and I'm working on 8.5 (exercises for chapter 8), decoupling the tests from the implementation.

In user_pages_spec.rb I didn't like the code

```
expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
```

Since `change(User, :count)` looks like a bit of a hack. So in spec/support/utilities.rb I wrote:

```
def create_user
    change(User, :count)
end
```

And I replaced the line in user_pages_spec.rb with

```
expect { click_button submit }.not_to create_user
```

Was this sensible?

Comment: What if you later will write tests for orders and books? Will you create similar methods, `create_order` and `create_book`? IMHO, this is unnecessary increase in complexity / LOCs.

Comment: Unless that `create_user` method is used all over I don't believe it aids comprehension enough to be justified. If it did, id consider a custom matcher that took a class anyway, or inferred the class from the test or subject's class.

Comment: what do you think about the answer below?

Answer (score 1):

Doing that is pretty much just "wrapping" the syntax, I don't think it really adds much to the code. The code you had earlier wasn't too bad, but perhaps you could also consider doing this:

```
expect { click_button submit }.to_not change{User.count}
```

Comment: The change{User.count} isn't working, but I'm satisfied that the original code was fine now.